# Default tab active not working in jquery and javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table to show with tabs on it. i have implemented it.

But having issue in when I reload the page of this table view, i need to make the tab 1 as active as defult. I have added the code, but it is not working

below is the page code

```js
function showDataInTable(data) {
        var wrapper = $("<div></div>");
        var wrapperUL = $("<ul class='nav nav-tabs'></ul>");
        var tabContentDiv = $("<div class='tab-content'></div>");
        var tab;
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++ ) {
            tab = data[i];
            wrapperUL.append('<li role="sheet_name" class="tab-li' + i + '"><a href="#' + i +
                '"       aria-controls="' + i + '" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">' + tab.sheetName +
                '</a></li>');
            
            var div = $('<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="' + i + '" sheet_name="' + tab.sheetName + '"></div>');
            var table = $('<table class="table table-condensed table-bordered table-hover"><thead><tr><th>#</th><th>Name</th><th class="danger" style="width:20%">Requirements</th><th class="success">Services</th><th>Location</th><th>Dimension</th></tr></thead><tbody></tbody></table>'); // create html tags as jQuery objects, not very long strings with data
            var rowCount = 0;
            for (var j = 0; j < tab.tabContent.length; j++) {
                var obj = tab.tabContent[j];

                // div += '<div sheet_name="' + obj.sheet_name + '">' + obj.name + '</div>';
                var row = $('<tr><td></td><td></td><td class="danger" style="width:20%"></td><td class="success"></td><td></td><td></td></tr>');
                rowCount++;
                row.find("td").eq(0).text(rowCount);
                row.find("td").eq(1).text(obj.name);
                row.find("td").eq(2).text(obj.requirements ? obj.requirements[0].requirement : '');
                row.find("td").eq(3).text(obj.services ? obj.services[0].service : '');
                row.find("td").eq(4).text(obj.location ? obj.location : '');
                row.find("td").eq(5).text(obj.dimensions ? obj.dimensions : '');
                table.find("tbody").append(row);

                if (obj.requirements || obj.services) {
                    var nMax = obj.services.length > obj.requirements.length ? obj.services.length : obj.requirements.length;
                    if (nMax > 1) {
                        var nRows = [];
                        for (var conut = 1; conut < nMax; conut++) {
                            nRows[conut] = $('<tr><td></td><td></td><td class="danger" style="width:20%"></td><td class="success"></td><td></td><td></td></tr>');
                            if (obj.requirements.length > conut) {
                                nRows[conut].find("td").eq(2).text(obj.requirements[conut].requirement);
                            }
                            if (obj.services.length > conut) {
                                nRows[conut].find("td").eq(3).text(obj.services[conut].service);
                            }
                        }
                        table.find("tbody").append(nRows);
                    }
                }
            }
            div.append(table);
            tabContentDiv.append(div);
        }
        $('.nav-tabs li').eq(0).addClass('active');
        $('.tab-content div').eq(0).addClass('active');

        wrapper.append(wrapperUL);
        wrapper.append("<p>&nbsp;</p>");
        wrapper.append(tabContentDiv);

        return wrapper;
    }
```

Comment: Your expertise @MoshFeu

Comment: Your expertise @Kaddath